# Return a map in C++ to use as a table in lua

Tags: c++, dictionary, lua

I want to be able to return a table of values, not userdata, stored data in a map, like integers, strings etc, in lua using C++. How would I go about doing this?

Sorry I don't have a complete example to give.

This is the map.

```
    std::map<uint16_t, std::map<std::string, uint32_t>> myMap;

    void getMyMap(uint16_t i, std::string a, uint32_t& v) {
        v = myMap[i][a];
    }
```

I know this isn't a template, but hypothetically if it was.

Edit :

I figured it out on my own. I won't give you exactly what I was working on but I will provide a generic detailed answer using the above code in mind.

```
std::map<uint16_t, std::map<std::string, uint32_t>> myMap;

void getMyMap(uint16_t i, std::string a, uint32_t& v) {
    v = myMap[i][a];
}

std::map<std::string, size_t> getMapData(uint16_t i){
    return myMap[i];
}


int LuaReturnTableOfMap(lua_State *L)
{
    uint16_t data = 2;// used just for this example
    // get the data stored
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m = getMapData(data);
    // get the size of the map
    size_t x = m.size();

    // create the table which we will be returning with x amount of elements
    lua_createtable(L, 0, x);

    // populate the table with values which we want to return
    for(auto const &it : m){
        std::string str = it.first;
        const char* field = str.c_str();
        lua_pushnumber(L, it.second);
        lua_setField(L, -2, field);
    }
    // tell lua we are returning 1 value (which is the table)
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recommend Sol2 (https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) enough for C++/Lua.

In c++ you can assigned nested maps and it is smart enough to created nested lua tables for you:

```
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int>> nestedmap;
std::map<std::string, int> innermap;
innermap["frank"] = 15;
nestedmap[2] = innermap;

sol::state lua;
lua.set("mymap", nestedmap);
```

Then in your lua script, you can access it just like a table:

```
print("Testing nested map: " .. mymap[2]["frank"]) -- prints 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am already using a framework for lua, its just that I am unsure of how to return a map or vector even. Your example doesn't really help me much.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unsure of your question. Are you just trying to return a std::map from a c++ function?